# How can I reference the location of nodes that are placed with the \graph command in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I've declared a graph like this:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph {1 -> 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to be able to reference the location of the nodes placed by the graph.

I tried using the same syntax that I use to name the locations of normal nodes:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph {1 (loc1) -> 2 (loc2)};
  \node at (loc1) {I am on top of node 1};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This gave me a syntax error though.

How *do* I reference the locations of nodes placed with the graph command?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that the location of every node is automatically named the same thing as its contents.

So here's a document that demonstrates that:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph {1 -> 2};
  \node at (1) {x};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Crossed out 1 arrow 2]

Comment: You can also use `alias`. `\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph {1[alias=a] -> 2[alias=b]};
  \path (a) node[above=1ex] {I am on top of node 1}
   (b) node[below=1ex] {I am below of node 2};
\end{tikzpicture}`